# How to retrieve the signification of a SNMP OID

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk

I'm working on SNMP protocol and analyzing a dump using **snmpwalk**. Each line starts by an OID like **iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0**, do you know how to get information about each OID ?

For example on wikipedia it's told that **1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2** correspond to the string **ifDescr**, but how to find all the others ?

Comment: What is the name of the MIB file you are using? As a reference you can take advantage of SNMP browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use oid-info.com

http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5&action=display

or install snmp-mibs-downloader and use snmptranslate

See https://l3net.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/installing-net-snmp-mibs-on-ubuntu-and-debian/